# Speed up python regex matching

Tags: python, regex

In python 're' module, I want to use a large number of calls ~ 1 million of re.findall() and re.sub(). I want to find all occurrences of a pattern in a string and then replace them with a fixed string. Ex. all dates in a strings are returned as a list and in original list, it was replaced by 'DATE'. How can I combine both into one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.sub)'s replace argument can be a callable:

```
dates = []
def store_dates(match):
    dates.append(match.group())
    return 'DATE'

data = re.sub('some-date-string', store_dates, data)

# data is now your data with all the date strings replaced with 'DATE'
# dates now has all of the date strings that matched your regex
```